# Need Some SQL help

Tags: syntax

I need to pass the following SQL statement:

```
UPDATE table_products 
SET shipping = "a:5:{s:16:"min_items_in_box"; i:0;s:16:"max_items_in_box"; i:0;s:10:"box_length";i:0;s:9:"box_width";i:0;s:10:"box_height";i:0;}";
```

I'm getting a syntax error from phpMyAdmin panel, asking to check the syntax. Could you please let me know what is wrong with the syntax?

Comment: What RDBMS is this for ???

Comment: Says phpmyadmin @RolandoMySQLDBA. I'd say RolandoSQL :)

Answer (score 3):

Pass strings to the dbms within single quotes, not within double quotes.

```
UPDATE table_products 
SET shipping = 'a:5:{s:16:"min_items_in_box";i:0;s:16:"max_items_in_box";i:0;s:10:"box_length";i:0;s:9:"box_width";i:0;s:10:"box_height";i:0;}';
```